# How do I use a variable as the value for the div title attribute

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, jstl

This spring message tag will display the property value of the samples.title.dialog variable on the page:

```
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="samples.title.dialog"/>
```

This div tag only shows the literal string "samples.title.dialog" on the page.

```
<div id="dialog" title="samples.title.dialog">
```

How do I use the value of the variable samples.title.dialog as the title of my div tag?  When I use the EL expression ${samples.title.dialog} as the title attribute it shows blank on the page.

I'm trying to use a div tag like this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="${samples.title.dialog}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [EL expression](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tutorials/jsp20/simpleel.html):

```
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="${samples.title.dialog}"/>
```

### UPDATE #1:

I think you might be referring to an attribute named `samples.title.dialog` associated with one of the four scopes: application, request, session or page. Try one of these:

```
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="${applicationScope['samples.title.dialog']}"/>
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="${requestScope['samples.title.dialog']}"/>
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="${sessionScope['samples.title.dialog']}"/>
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="${pageScope['samples.title.dialog']}"/>
```

### UPDATE #2:

It looks like you're actually trying to use a value defined in a Spring Internationalization properties file. Check out this [Spring Internationalization example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html) and verify that you've done all the steps correctly to wire things up.

Comment: I misspoke in my question.  It's updated to say "How do I use the value of the variable samples.title.dialog as the title of my div tag?"  When I use the EL expression ${samples.title.dialog} as the title attribute it shows blank on the page.

Comment: @Kevin: I've updated my answer. Is what you're trying to use actually an "attribute"?

Comment: I believe it is an "attribute".  The value will display when I use a spring:message tag.  It won't display when I attempt to use the same EL expression as the input for the title attribute of a div tag.  I tried all 4 scopes and did not get a value.

Comment: It's in a spring internationalization properties file as:  samples.title.dialog=Dialog

Comment: If it helps anything the div tag I'm using is a jqueryui div tag for a dialog.

Comment: @Kevin: Ok, I've update my answer again. Looks like this is *not* an EL expression question. So take out the EL expression. There is quite a bit of XML plumbing needed for Spring internationalization to work. Follow the example in the link I posted and hopefully it should get you on the right track.

Comment: I just tried something I hadn't before.  I didn't realize that whole spring:message tag should be used as the title value like this:  '<div id="dialog" title="<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" text="${samples.title.dialog}"/>">'.  I had only previously tried like this:  '<div id="dialog" title="${samples.title.dialog}">'.  Passing in the whole Spring:message tag worked.  Thanks for your help.  Is there anything wrong with doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

```
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" var="i18n_dialog" />
${i18n_dialog}
```

Note: You can't do this, because samples.title.dialog is a read-only property:

```
<spring:message code="samples.title.dialog" var="samples.title.dialog" />
```